# Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null on TextArea

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I'm just learning some react stuff at the moment and am running into an error when trying to implement https://www.npmjs.com/package/textarea-markdown this.

I think the error comes from the fact that the script is attempting to change the textarea before the textarea is loaded, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated

Code below

text.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './texts.css';
import TextareaMarkdown from 'textarea-markdown'

let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
new TextareaMarkdown(textarea);


function Texts() {
    
  return (
    <div >
        <h2>Editor</h2>
            <textarea id="editor" data-preview="#preview"></textarea>
        <h2>Preview</h2>
    <div id="preview"></div>
    </div>
  );
  
}



export default Texts;
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Texts from './components/texts/texts';



function App() {
  
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Texts></Texts>
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

The error I receive is this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
TextareaMarkdown.setPreview
node_modules/textarea-markdown/lib/textarea-markdown.js:65
  62 | value: function setPreview() {
  63 |   var _this2 = this;
  64 | 
> 65 |   var selector = this.textarea.getAttribute('data-preview');
     | ^  66 |   if (selector) {
  67 |     Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector), function (e) {
  68 |       return _this2.previews.push(e);
View compiled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use you following code inside a `useEffect`
as like following

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import './texts.css';
import TextareaMarkdown from 'textarea-markdown'


function Texts() {

useEffect(()=>{
 let textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
 new TextareaMarkdown(textarea);
},[]);


  return (
    <div >
        <h2>Editor</h2>
            <textarea id="editor" data-preview="#preview"></textarea>
        <h2>Preview</h2>
    <div id="preview"></div>
    </div>
  );
  
}



export default Texts;
```

Comment: For reference: "By using this Hook, you tell React that your component needs to do something after render." [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).